# Parsing a parameter with options while executing the shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have 5 options in a script like Getting IP address, Free memory, CPU usage, Hostname and Username.

I want to do one script to get the all output or anyone.

For example :

If I execute

```
system_info.sh -i ip -fm free -c cpu -h host -u user
```

or

```
system_info.sh -all all
```

then it should give all the output.

If suppose I want only one output, need to run the same script like

```
system_info.sh -fm free
system_info.sh -fm free -i ip
```

I have the idea but I don't know how to set these options and validate in a script.

Please suggest me how to set these options

Comment: Refer to [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/192249/4518341)

Answer (score 5):

I have never done this before but saw this and I learnt something. You will need to use the `bash` `getopts` function like so. This should point you in the right direction:

```
while getopts i:f:c:h:u: option
do
 case "${option}"
 in
 i) ip=${OPTARG};;
 f) state=${OPTARG};;
 c) cpu=${OPTARG};;
 h) host=$OPTARG;;
 u) user=$OPTARG;;
 esac
done
```

This is a while-loop that uses the `getopts` function and a so-called `optstring`, in this case `i:f:c:h:u:`, to iterate through the arguments. The while-loop walks through the `optstring`, which contains the flags that can be used to pass arguments, and assigns the argument value provided for that flag to the variable `option`. The case-statement then assigns the value of the variable `option` to a global variable that can used after all the arguments have been read.

The colons in the `optstring` mean that values are required for the corresponding flags. In the above example all flags are followed by a colon: `i:f:c:h:u:`.

This means, all flags need a value. If, for example, the `i` and `u` flags were not expected to have a value, the optstring would be `i:f:c:h:u`.

A colon at the beginning of the optstring, for example `:i:f:c:h:u:`, has a completely different meaning. It allows you to handle flags that are not represented in the optstring. In that case the value of the "option" variable is set to "?" and the value of "OPTARG" is set to the unexpected flag. The allows you to display a suitable error message informing the user of the mistake.

Arguments that are not preceded by a flag are ignored by getopts. If flags specified in the optstring are not provided when the script is called, nothing happens, unless you specially handle this case in your code.

Any arguments not handled by `getops` can still be captured with the regular `$1`, `$2`, etc. variables.

Simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "i:f:c:h:u:" opt
do
        case $opt in
                i)
                        echo "ip"
                        ;;
                f)
                        echo "free"
                        ;;
                c)
                        echo "cpu"
                        ;;
                h)
                        echo "host"
                        ;;
                u)
                        echo "user"
                        ;;
                *)
                        echo "Nothing to do"
                        ;;
        esac
done
```

Usage:

```
./h.sh -i ip -f free -c cpu -h host -u user
```

Result:

```
ip
free
cpu
host
user
```

Source:

https://www.lifewire.com/pass-arguments-to-bash-script-2200571

http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing

Comment: If you know it will work then share pls

Comment: @user476625 Are you asking for a sample code?

Comment: Yes, what ever you shared already read that link

Comment: Thanks in Advance, still trying but i am not able get. if you did please share

Comment: do we need the getopts, without getopts script cant work ?

Comment: @user476625 Of course there are ways to do this without `getopts`, just that this is the most convenient – see e.g. [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash).

Comment: I tried that code also, if i want one output that code not working for me

Comment: You can suggest what need to be done

Comment: @user476625 If this answer doesn't solve your question please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/960115/edit) it and clarify stating exactly what you need and what's wrong with `getopts`, stop spamming with comments!

Comment: Please read the comments i have asked without getopts, dont blame others

Comment: @user476625 No, I won't. Instead, I'm voting to close this question now as it's unclear what you're asking. You're welcome to edit and clarify.

Comment: if you are not to help others dont disturb or dont dominate others do your work

Comment: @George `getopts fm:` will create two options, one `-f` without an argument and one `-m` with an argument – as far as I know it's not possible to add multicharacter options using `getopts`, cf. [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial): *Note that getopts is not able to parse GNU-style long options (--myoption) or XF86-style long options (-myoption)!*

Comment: ok @dessert thanks for the heads up will look more at these when creating something for OP

Comment: @George I have one more query in that, If suppose one default option will be there. for example execute like                                            

       test.sh -all -v system1.

so -v will default one and passing argument is different. what we need to do in that case

Comment: @user476625 which is the default argument `-all` or `-v`, in any case since it's defult no need to add it at the command line it would be used inside your code unknown to the user but would be in the documentation.

Comment: For example username parameter is default whenever execute the script we need to execute with -u user and then what we need to pass. Because there are no. of users right. 
test.sh -u user -f mem

Comment: That can be done with the `$USER` `env variable`, this should be done in the code itself, or run like `test.sh -u user` then you check to make sure the user running it is the right one

Comment: "If, for example, the `i` and `u` flags were not expected to have a value, the optstring would be `i:f:c:h:u`." Do you mean `if:c:h:u`?